# For loop only updates one field or not at all

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects, opportunity-lineitem, before-trigger

I wrote a method that takes a filtered list of OpportunityLineItems and tries to update two date fields based on some logic in a Before Update. When I write it like this only the first field is updated.

```
private static void checkSubscription(List<OpportunityLineItem> filtered)
{
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : filtered)
    {
        if(
            oli.Product2.Product_Type__c == 'Subscription' &&
            oli.Trend__c == null
        )
            oli.Revenue_Received_End_Date__c = oli.End_Date__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
            oli.Revenue_Received_Start_Date__c = oli.Start_Date__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
    }
}
```

If I write it like this to encompass both actions in `{}` neither field updates.

```
private static void checkSubscription(List<OpportunityLineItem> filtered)
{
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : filtered)
    {
        if(
            oli.Product2.Product_Type__c == 'Subscription' &&
            oli.Trend__c == null
        )
        {
            oli.Revenue_Received_End_Date__c = oli.End_Date__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
            oli.Revenue_Received_Start_Date__c = oli.Start_Date__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and doesn't throw an error just values are not populating when expected. What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first block *unconditionally* sets the `Revenue_Received_Start_Date__c` field. That is because when you omit brackets around a block in `Apex`, the next statement is treated as the relevant block. So your logic in the first block can be rewritten as:

```
if (/*some condition*/)
{
    // set Revenue_Received_End_Date__c
}
// set Revenue_Received_Start_Date__c
```

Hence why you see updates when you omit brackets, but not when you include them. Because if you are filtering on trigger context records, `Product2.Product_Type__c` will always be null. Instead, you may want to simply query for your `'Subscription'` products and create an Id whitelist.

```
Set<Id> subscriptionProductIds = new Map<Id, Product2>([
    SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Product_Type__c = 'Subscription'
]).keySet();

// in your loop:
if (oli.Trend__c == null && subscriptionProductIds.contains(oli.Product2Id);
{
    // set both revenue fields
}
```

Comment: If I had a formula field that displayed the product product_type__c field, then I could get around making the query right? What I'm concerned with is I have 56k products 39k of them that are subscription. I don't want to slow things down too much..